# Drag Drop behavior not as expected

Tags: c#, html, jqgrid, drag-and-drop

When I drag from my first grid (left on the image) to my second grid (right on my image) I have to hover the item over the area that I circeled with red.... If I don't drop it there, it hops back to the first grid.

[image: Drag Drop Image]

This is not how I would expect the grids to work together?

**Expected is:** If I drop a item anywhere in the grid, it should drop itself into that grid.

Is there any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `height: "auto"` option in both grids. The current problem is that you use the option `connectWith: "#grid2"` of [gridDnD](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajquery_ui_methods#drag_and_drop_rows_between_grids) method, but the second grid with id=grid2 **consist from only the part of the destination table which you marked red**. Other part of "the grid" is **`<div>`** element existing over the `<table id="grid2">`. So drag&drop can't work like you expect. You try to drop **outside** of the destination grid.